# Angular2 Relative Paths with Webpack 2

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

So I'm running through the tour-of-heroes tutorial on the angular.io website except i'm using webpack instead of systemjs.

Everything was running smoothly until I got to the part about templates and using relative paths indicating that I need to specify "module.id" in the component for relative paths to work. Unfortunately using module.id did nothing and I was still receiving 404 errors using webpack-dev-server. The project was still trying to load the templates from the root.

I also tried using the "./" syntax on the templateUrls so that webpack could resolve these issues for me, but running webpack-dev-server still ran into those 404 issues.

Is anyone else having these problems?

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Hero } from "./hero";
import { HeroService } from "./hero.service";

@Component({
    moduleId: String(module.id),
    selector: "my-dashboard",
    templateUrl: "./dashboard.component.html"
})
export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    heroes: Hero[] = [];

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.heroService.getHeroes().then(heroes => this.heroes = heroes.slice(1, 5));
    }

    constructor(private heroService: HeroService) {}
}
```

[image: Chrome Debugger]

Comment: Have you tried removing the `moduleId` property? I don't think it's needed with webpack.

Answer (score 0):

In order for relative path to work with webpack you have to use

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';



@Component({ selector: 'my-app',
 template: require('./header.component.html'), styles: [require('./header.component.css')] })



export class HeaderComponent implements OnInit { }
```

And when we use system.js we use

If we decide to use SystemJS, we use __moduleName variable instead of the module.id variable

Please find the link this will help you better.

[Help link](https://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2016/06/08/component-relative-paths-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: I actually tried this method, but was receiving typescript compilation errors.

Comment: I tried and it is working fine for me can you add the console log for the same, also check the help link

Comment: this is the compilation error i'm receiving from webpack:

Comment: Is this path correct D:\ng2-tour-of-heroes\src\app\dashboard.component.html. Is it pointing to the correct path?

Comment: Then i guess its not the relative path error its some thing else, as webpack now supports relative paths

Comment: Could you link me your webpack configuration?

Comment: I am using webpack starter kit .here is my gut hub link you can check it out https://github.com/rahulrsingh09

Answer (score 0):

Ok so in order to use require('./template.html') to embed the templates into your component, you need this loader for webpack called angular2-template-loader and raw-loader